# Рекурсия, return, ошибка:TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия, return

Не понимаю, почему выходит ошибка `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`, и почему счетчик `count` постоянна обнуляется, если в `return` убрать `, count`

Из задачи: Начав тренировки, лыжник в первый день пробежал 10 км. Каждый следующий день он увеличивал пробег на 10% от пробега предыдущего дня.

```
def Distance(d, count=0):
    if d==0:
        return 10
    else:
        res= Distance(d - 1) * (1 + 0.1) #считаем 10% от предыдущего значения и прибавляем к нему же.
        count += res                     # заносим результат в общий счетчик.
        print(round(res,2),'',count) # печатаем расстояние, которое пройдет сегодня и общее пройденное расстояние.
        return res, count

print(Distance(3))
```

Буду очень благодарен, если разъясните. А то совсем не понимаю что происходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас функция возвращает кортеж из двух чисел - res и count.

Но в этой строке

```
res= Distance(d - 1) * (1 + 0.1)
```

вы пытаетесь работать с возвращаемым значением функции, как будто там одно число.

Нужно как-то так:

```
def Distance(d):
    if d==0:
        return 10, 10
    else:
        prev_res, prev_count = Distance(d - 1)
        res = prev_res * (1 + 0.1)
        count = prev_count + res
        print(round(res,2),'',count)
        return res, count

Distance(3)
```

И, кстати, это такое требование в задаче - решать её через рекурсию? Потому что гораздо проще было бы её решить через формулу суммы геометрической прогрессии

Comment: получается, вы создаете переменные  `prev_res` и `prev_count` и в них, когда функция дойдет до крайнего случая  `d==0`, будет значение 10. Затем на обратном ходу уже вычисляется значение для остальных случаев, если я правильно понимаю.

Но, я не понял в чем суть этой ошибки:

`res= Distance(d - 1) * (1 + 0.1)`

"вы пытаетесь работать с возвращаемым значением функции, как будто там одно число".
И да, это требование: решать через рекурсию.

Comment: @VyQwe, Вы умножаете то, что возвращает функция на 1.1 Но функция возвращает кортеж из двух значений, а кортеж нельзя умножать на дробное число. Поэтому и была ошибка.

Comment: то есть, чтобы я мог так сделать, мне нужно как бы распаковать кортеж, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да. Если функция возвращает несколько значений, то её результат либо нужно сразу распаковать в несколько переменных, либо использовать дальше как кортеж.